# AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'update'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-multiprocessing

I have the issue : "AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'update'"

How could I solve it ?

code :

```
queue = Queue()
    liste = glob(f+'/2013/*.xml')[:30]
    # l1 = Manager().list
    # l2
    # # for fic in liste : 
    #   grosse_bc = main(fic,listeIngr,listeAll,grosse_bc)
    # for i in range (50): 
    #   main(liste[i],listeIngr,listeAll,grosse_bc)
    while len(liste) >= 15 :
        for i in range(15):
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=main, args=(liste[i],listeIngr,listeAll,queue,grosse_bc))
            jobs.append(p)
            p.start()
        liste = liste[14:]
    print("fini !")
    # for p in jobs :
    #   # grosse_bc.update(p)
    #   p.join()
    # print("join fini !")
    gros_dico = []
    # queue.join()
    x = 0
    tgd = {}
    while not queue.empty():
        # gros_dico.append(queue.get())
        for elem in queue.get():
            if elem not in tgd :
                tgd[elem] = queue.get().values()
            else : 
                tgd[elem].update(queue.get().values())
    # print(gros_dico)
    # for elem in gros_dico :
    #   tgd.update(elem)
    pprint(tgd)
```

And I would like to concatenate all the dicts outputed by the queues. 
Best 
Leon

Comment: You should show the `main` method

Comment: `tgd[elem]` is apparently of type `dict_values`, and that type has no `update` attribute.